# How do i fix "soap:VersionMismatch" in wso2 4.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I created a soap-to-rest API, but testing it, I'm getting the "soap:VersionMismatch" error, I've researched on possible solutions, but on this version, can't seem to find where to set the "mediator sequence" that most solution suggest. I've tried adding the in sequence to policies, but it makes no difference.

here is the error

```
{
  "Envelope": {
    "Body": {
      "Fault": {
        "faultcode": "soap:VersionMismatch",
        "faultstring": "A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is the sequence I add to the policies, and it doesn't seem to do anything, and I'm not getting any log

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ConvertToSoap11">
    <log description="Content_before_modification" level="full"/>
    <property name="transport.soap.Version" value="soap11" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="FORCE_SOAP_1_1" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="COPY_CONTENT_LENGTH_FROM_INCOMING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
    <log description="Content_after_modification" level="full"/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SOAP 1.2 WSDL, you might have to change the message format to  1.2 under advanced configurations in the Endpoints section in the Publisher portal and redeploy the API

[image]

Comment: I have a soap 1.1 WSDL, changing it here still gives the same error